# What do you call these advertising popups on greyed background overlaid on the web page you're reading

Tags: popup, advertisement

I see more and more of these.

Use case: You're reading an article on some news web site and after a while, when you're half way through, a popup gets in the way proposing to subscribe to some marketing offer.

I guess there is a technical term for this; what is it?

Comment: I believe the technical term is "annoying popup that always get in my way ads". Also known as "where's the X button ads"?

Comment: @BartGijssens, lol. The ones that don't have an X button you can get rid of with firebug or the equiv dev tools. Or some URL tweak (e.g. for quora adding ?share=1).

Comment: @BartGijssens That was exactly what I was going to comment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I really needed a word for this so I coined one. I'll call that stuff a nag-up.

Comment: @From Review. This does provides an answer to [my] question. That's at least as I see it - as the OP :).

Answer (score 2):

They are called MODAL BOXES or MODAL WINDOWS

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modal_window

in this case they are either timed or triggered by an action by the user, such as scrolling or trying to close the page

Answer (score 1):

You can call it **pop-up windows**. A pop-up window is a type of window that opens without the user selecting "New Window" from a program's File menu.

Pop-up windows are often generated by websites that include pop-up advertisements. These ads are produced with JavaScript code that is inserted into the HTML of a Web page. They typically appear when a user visits a page or closes a window.

Answer (score 0):

Technically they are "lightboxes", not model windows because that is a different thing in javascript, but you're looking for a conceptual name, which I don't believe I heard before, I use the term "late lightbox" or "auto lightbox" to indicate that it is not user initiated.